# Occasional spike in nscanned for a MongoDB query

Tags: mongodb

I have a query of the form

```
db.coll.find({x: {$in: ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']}).sort({_id:-1}).limit(LIMIT)
```

"x" is a single ObjectId field, _id is an ObjectId too. There is an index {x:1, _id:-1}. This query should be hitting the fast path from [#SERVER-5063](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-5063%20#SERVER-5063).

It does so most of the time, except some rare instances where it appears that a full table scan is performed - the profile entry for these queries shows nscanned to be slightly above the count of all documents matching `{x: {$in: ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']}}`. That's usually some 3 orders of magnitude above what the query scans in the expected case.

The collection is fairly write heavy, so my first guess was that perhaps the query optimizer was retrying various query plans, including the `{_id:1}` index, but the spikes remain even after adding `.hint({x:1, _id:-1})`, so I'm not sure what's going on here.

Can anyone explain the occasional scan of all documents matching the query and how to prevent it?

edit: happens on MongoDB 2.4.4

Comment: Can you check the index used at that time, may be using the query profiler? Also fire the exact query with same value of `'x'` at some different time, and compare the nscanned value. There is something called `idhack` in which we have experienced that mongodb ignore the `hint` and chooses to used `_id` index.

Comment: The correct index ({x:1, _id:-1}) is used, according to the profiler. When I take a query from the profile and run it with explain(), I get the expected result - a 3 orders of magnitude lower nscanned and 4 orders of magnitude lower millis. Didn't notice "idhack" in the profile or explain() output.

Comment: This is weird, same query behaving differently despite of using the same index. May be you should create a JIRA ticket and get a followup from 10gen.